# botão para exibir/ocultar div

Tags: javascript, html, div

Tenho uma div que gostaria de ocultar e exibir através de um botão. No entanto quando clico nesse botão, ao invés dele ocultar/exibir a div, o formulário acaba sendo enviado. Vejam o trecho de código abaixo:

```
<form name="form1" class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="salvar_dados.php">

    <button id="btnExibeOcultaDiv" class="btn btn-info"   onclick="ocultarExibir();">Exibe_Oculta</button>
    <br/>

    <div class="col-md-1" id="dvPrincipal"><!-- Div principal-->

            <label for="qtd_bola_azul">Bola Azul</label>
        <input class="form-control" id="qtd_bola_azul" name="qtd_bola_azul" value="0" type="number"/>

    </div><!-- Fim Div principal-->

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="sendListaAluno">Enviar Lista</button>


</form>

<script type="text/javascript">

            var visibilidade = true; //Variável que vai manipular o botão Exibir/ocultar


            function ocultarExibir(){ // Quando clicar no botão.

                if(visibilidade){//Se a variável visibilidade for igual a true, então...
                    document.getElementById("dvPrincipal").style.display = "none";//Ocultamos a div
                    visibilidade = false;//alteramos o valor da variável para falso.
                }else{//ou se a variável estiver com o valor false..
                    document.getElementById("dvPrincipal").style.display = "block";//Exibimos a div..
                    visibilidade = true;//Alteramos o valor da variável para true.
                }
            }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Já que está usando Bootstrap, pode usar os recursos do jQuery que torna bem mais fácil com o método [.toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/), que alterna entre *mostrar* e *esconder* um elemento, sem necessidade de usar `onclick` ou colocar `type="button"` no botão. Além de reduzir significativamente linhas de código.

Basta criar um evento `.click` para o botão e o `.toggle()` na div:

```js
$("#btnExibeOcultaDiv").click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault(); // evita que o formulário seja submetido
   $("#dvPrincipal").toggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<form name="form1" class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="salvar_dados.php">

    <button id="btnExibeOcultaDiv" class="btn btn-info">Exibe_Oculta</button>
    <br/>

    <div class="col-md-1" id="dvPrincipal"><!-- Div principal-->

            <label for="qtd_bola_azul">Bola Azul</label>
        <input class="form-control" id="qtd_bola_azul" name="qtd_bola_azul" value="0" type="number"/>

    </div><!-- Fim Div principal-->

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="sendListaAluno">Enviar Lista</button>


</form>
```

Comment: Ótimo, muito bom dessa forma.

Answer (score 1):

Adicione `type="button"` no botão:

```
<button type="button" id="btnExibeOcultaDiv" class="btn btn-info"   onclick="ocultarExibir();">Exibe_Oculta</button>
```

Comment: Sensacional!!!! Deu certinho!! Muito agradecido!!